# get the post content associated with the selected comment (Method post does not exist)

Tags: laravel

I have this code to get the post content associated with the selected comment:

```
$postContent = Comment::find($commentID)->post()->first();
```

But it shows "Method post does not exist.".

Comment model:

```
public function post(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Post', 'post_id');
}
```

Post model:

```
 public function comments(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'post_id');
 }
```

Comment: what is a result `dd(Comment::find($commentID));`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
$postContent = Comment::find($commentID)->post;
```

Comment: Thanks, it shows "Property [post] does not exist on this collection instance.
".